# Web Scraping Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping

I'm trying to input data based on column "A" into column "B". If "A" is a comprehensive list of website urls, would it be possible to run a script that scrapes the phone numbers, for example, from these websites and inputs into column "B"?

I am 100% newbie to scripting, but would love to learn how this works.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each cell in `Column A` is one url, you definitely can scrape for phone numbers.

[image]

**The code to achieve this:**

- Extract the webpage's text *(assuming the phone number isn't structured as a link or something else)*.
- Search that text for phone numbers using regex.

```
B2: =JOIN("|",IMPORTXML(A2,"//a/@href"))
C2: =REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"[0-9]{3}[- ]*[0-9]{3}[- ]*[0-9]{4}")
```

Comment: thank you for the response! 

IMPORTXML doesn't pull any of the content of the page, and won't let me then search for the phone number in C2.

Comment: What's the URL you're using? (It could have some protection against bots...)